# How should I implement "else if" in web assembly?

Tags: if-statement, compiler-construction, antlr, webassembly

I am building a project that makes use of ANTLR to parse a custom language grammar that I have created, and my task is to compile/transpile this code into Web Assembly.

This is a snippet of example code that I may try convert using the program:

```
if (<condition>) {
    <some code>
}
else if (<condition>) {
    <some code>
}
else {
    <some code>
}
```

I am not experienced with Web Assembly in the slightest, however it is a requirement for the project. It seems "if" and "else" statements are fairly straight forward, my only issue is the "else if" statement.

The only way I can think to implement it is to nest all the "else if" statements within the "else" clause of the selection above it, as there does not seem to be any web assembly syntax to support a direct "else if" statement.

Any advice that can be suggested would be fantastic, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> The only way I can think to implement it is to nest all the "else if" statements within the "else" clause of the selection above it

Yes, that's exactly how you do it.

PS: You might be interested to know that many languages do in fact not have a dedicated else-if syntax. For example, in C and many of its descendants the syntax for if statements is as follows:

```
statement: 'if' '(' expression ')' statement ('else' statement)?
```

So an `else if` is simply `else` followed by an if statement. So even at the syntactical level in many languages an `else if` is simply an if statement inside an else branch.

Since your syntax looks similar, you could probably also write your grammar in this way, so you wouldn't need to do anything at all to support `else if`s.

Answer (score 2):

> The only way I can think to implement it is to nest all the "else if"
>   statements within the "else" clause of the selection above it

Yes, that is an entirely valid approach. However, as well as [`if`](https://github.com/sunfishcode/wasm-reference-manual/blob/master/WebAssembly.md#if) and [`else`](https://github.com/sunfishcode/wasm-reference-manual/blob/master/WebAssembly.md#else) instructions, there is also the option to use [`select`](https://github.com/sunfishcode/wasm-reference-manual/blob/master/WebAssembly.md#select), which returns either the first or second operand based on a condition.

To see how other languages approach this problem I'd recommend having a go with [WebAssembly Studio](https://webassembly.studio/).

For example, the following ActionScript code:

```js
export function if_else_test(input: i32): i32 {
  if (input > 10) {
    return 101;
  } else if (input > 20) {
    return 102;
  } else {
    return 103;
  }
}
```

is compiled to the following:

```
  (func $if_else_test (export "if_else_test") (type $t1) (param $p0 i32) (result i32)
    i32.const 101
    i32.const 102
    i32.const 103
    get_local $p0
    i32.const 20
    i32.gt_s
    select
    get_local $p0
    i32.const 10
    i32.gt_s
    select)
```

The above code loads the stack with the three different return values, then uses a couple of select statements to return the correct value based on the two if conditions.

Although the logic can be easier to follow if re-written using the 'function call' syntax:

```
  (func $if_else_test (export "if_else_test") (type $t1) (param $p0 i32) (result i32)
    (select
      (i32.const 101)
      (select 
        (i32.const 102)
        (i32.const 103)
        (i32.gt_s
          (i32.const 20)
          (get_local $p0)
        )
      )
      (i32.gt_s
        (i32.const 10)
        (get_local $p0)
      )
    )
```